# How many file descriptors created/involved after running this program - pipe

Tags: c, pipe

From the below program,

```
/***************************************************************************** 
 MODULE: popen.c
 *****************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        FILE *pipein_fp, *pipeout_fp;
        char readbuf[80];

        /* Create one way pipe line with call to popen() */
        if (( pipein_fp = popen("ls", "r")) == NULL)
        {
                perror("popen");
                exit(1);
        }

        /* Create one way pipe line with call to popen() */
        if (( pipeout_fp = popen("sort", "w")) == NULL)
        {
                perror("popen");
                exit(1);
        }

        /* Processing loop */
        while(fgets(readbuf, 80, pipein_fp))
                fputs(readbuf, pipeout_fp);

        /* Close the pipes */
        pclose(pipein_fp);
        pclose(pipeout_fp);

        return(0);
}
```

---

`popen.c` is compiled to `my_program`

Here is my understanding of the file descriptors created/involved after executing `my_program`, `popen()` forks & execs the `my_program` process but child processes does not inherit the pipe file descriptors of `my_program`.

So, After exec,

1) write file descriptor is only created for `ls`

2) read file descriptor is only created for `sort`

3) read and write files descriptors are created in `my_program`, because `ls` writes to `my_program` & `sort` reads from `my_program`

[image]

---

As shown above, Are these the only file descriptors involved/created?

*Note: 'in' & 'out' are just naming conventions used here*

Comment: Child processes from a `fork()` have exactly the same set of open file descriptors as the parent process.  The `popen()` call uses `pipe()` to create two file descriptors; it then executes `fork()`.  The parent process arranges that one end of the pipe is closed and the other converted to a file stream (`FILE *`).  The child process closes the other end of the pipe and arranges for the one end to become standard input (`"w"`) or standard output (`"r"`) for the process it executes.  You use `popen()` twice; you end up with 2 open descriptors in the parent, and transiently there's a third.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 1) When you say, *The parent process arranges that one end of the pipe is closed*. Do you mean read file descriptor(stdin)? 2) Do all process thru `popen()` make sure they `dup` to make sure they use `stdout`  &  `stdin`?

Comment: Each pipe has a read end and a write end.  Take `popen("ls", "r")`; your program reads from the `ls` process.  It (`popen()`) creates a pipe and forks.  In the child, the write end of the pipe is connected to stdout (`dup2()` or perhaps `dup()`), and the read end of the pipe is closed, before the command is executed.  In the parent, the read end of the pipe is 'converted to' or 'attached to' a stream (`fdopen()`, more or less) and the write end of the pipe is closed.  In the parent process, the pipe is never connected to either `stdout` or `stdin`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler got u sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child processes from a `fork()` have exactly the same set of open file descriptors as the parent process.

The `popen()` call uses `pipe()` to create two file descriptors; it then executes `fork()`. The parent process arranges that one end of the pipe is closed and the other converted to a file stream (`FILE *`). The child process closes the other end of the pipe and arranges for the one end to become standard input (`"w"`) or standard output (`"r"`) for the process it executes (using `dup()` or `dup2()` for the task).

You use `popen()` twice; you end up with 2 open descriptors in the parent, and transiently there's a third.

> 1. When you say, 'the parent process arranges that one end of the pipe is closed', do you mean read file descriptor (`stdin`)?

Depending on the mode argument to `popen()`, one of the two ends of the pipe in the parent is closed immediately; the other is closed by `pclose()`.  The file descriptor is 'never' the one for standard input or standard output — you have to go through extraordinary gyrations to make it so that is one of the standard I/O channels.

> 2. Do all process thru `popen()` make sure they `dup()` to make sure they use stdout & stdin?

Each pipe has a read end and a write end. Take `popen("ls", "r")`; your program reads from the `ls` process. It (`popen()`) creates a pipe and forks. In the child, the write end of the pipe is connected to `stdout` (`dup2()` or perhaps `dup()`), and the read end of the pipe is closed, before the command is executed. In the parent, the read end of the pipe is 'converted to' or 'attached to' a stream (`fdopen()`, more or less) and the write end of the pipe is closed. In the parent process, the pipe is never connected to either stdout or stdin.

In the child process, either standard input or standard output is connected to the pipe, depending on the mode argument to `popen()`.

Comment: In parent process, after the first popen(), read file stream is created, write end of pipe is closed, after second popen(), write stream is created, read end of pipe is closed. Transiently third pipe? Where is that?

Comment: Each pipe has two descriptors.  Parent does: pipe + 2 descriptors; close - 1; pipe + 2; close -1: net gain 2, but the sum was +2, +1, +3, +2 at the various steps.  Hence the transient 3rd descriptor.